# What is the correct way to properly align the subscript with \mathcal?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am writing `\mathcal{H_S}` in code, and this is what renders:

[image: \mathcal{H_S}]

It seems to me that the spacing between the H and S is excessive, and indeed `\mathcal{H_{\!S}}` seems to produce a more natural spacing. I suspect this is not the correct way to do it though. What do you recommend?

Note, I have the following in my preamble.

```latex
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: it's as good as anything, the font metrics specify the spacing but the core tex font metrics are not going to change ever so adjusting it to your liking is not unreasonable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good to know, thank you.